# Заполнение компонентов при открытой форме поверх окон

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Как разрешить пользователю вносить значения в компоненты на нижней форме, при открытой форме поверх окон?
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хм... Может, я уже достаточно хорошо забыл Delphi XE, но в в последних версиях Delphi (проверил сейчас в 10.2) это делается просто вызовом дочерней формы методом `Show`, а не `ShowModal`. Получается, как на скриншоте (я не стал добавлять на формы много элементов, но и так видно, что дочерняя форма сверху, тогда как я спокойно редактирую текст в `TEdit` на родительской форме):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В вашем случае (Delphi XE), возможно, надо еще обязательно выставить в свойствах дочерней формы стиль `fsStayOnTop` (а если это не поможет, то пробовать играться с `SetWindowPos(Form.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOMOVE);`)